# Must, I adhere to general standards when showing a problem?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I've been put on hold for being unclear. And, I believe it is my lack of understanding the conventional standards. (Which I find difficult to follow in most cases)

I have updated the question containing details that I have a legitimate algorithm that is linear and takes any arbitrary **Sudoku**. Then reduces it into a **Max-Sat Sudoku**.

### Question

*Is there anything, that I can do to improve the question as I am lacking the mathematical experience needed to show that my claim is true?*

[Reducing Sudoku <p Max-Sat instance in Sudoku form](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109925/reducing-sudoku-p-max-sat-instance-in-sudoku-form)

Comment: Drop your sudoku for some time and learn reductions without latin squares or mapper. Yes, you have to adhere to standards. If you want to prove something, you need a proof, not hand-waving argument with your sudoku program as sugar coating. I think, that you over-exaggerate with venture to find some high complexity class to your puzzle toy.

Comment: @Evil  It is done. The Sudoku project. It works. It works for n! of n^2 x n^2. Good enough for me.  Its done.  https://repl.it/repls/SerpentineBogusKernelmode

Comment: Please think how far 5 lines of code (one accumulator, one loop, 3 instructions where two are append and one is concatenation) could pose NPH or NPC problem, how far you need to stretch your ideas to present "Invalid Sudoku Puzzle". It is harmful to you and cumbersome for us. Please look at number of comments asking for clarification. It isn't working. If project is done, please get a book and drop any sudoku related reduction.

Comment: @Evil, that code was just a rough draft. It only poses easy instances of Sudoku. And, yes its n! of n^2 x n^2. How far. At least up to 50x50 if not 100x100.   Besides, its time to shelve it. I'm content with it.